# Calling a structure from a structure in a function in C

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

In my program, I got 2 structures:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct human {
  struct human_header *human_header;
  char *name;
};

struct human_header {
  unsigned short number;
};

void f2(struct human_header *human_header) {
  human_header->number = 1;
}

void f1(struct human *human) {
  f2(human->human_header);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv) {
  struct human *human;
  f1(human);
  printf("END\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why I have a segmentation fault... Can somebody explain me?

Comment: You are using `struct human *human` without initializing it first. BTW, get rid of that identical symbol for the variable type and for the variable name. There are other words in the English vocabulary besides `human`.

Comment: You need to allocate memory for the structure

Answer (score 1):

You get a segmentation fault because human and human->header are uninitialized.
you should do the following:

```
human = malloc(sizeof(struct human));
human->header = malloc(sizeof(struct human_header));
f1(human);
free(human->header);
free(human);
```

Comment: `human` is not `NULL`, it is an uninitialized variable (could be any value). You're also forgetting to tell OP that they should call `free(human)` at a later point in the execution of the program. And of course, you should also consider the option of allocating `human` at function `main` on the stack, and passing its address (in which case, calling `free` would not be necessary).

Comment: You need to include `stdlib.h` in order to use `malloc` and also free the allocated memory after its use.

Answer (score 0):

The line of code

```
 stuct human* human;
```

creates an automatic variable `human` that will contain the address of human structure.  No where in your code did you actually create that structure.

So what you need to do is this;

```
int main (int argc, char *argv) {
    struct human *human = malloc(sizeof(struct human));

    if(NULL != human) {
        human->human_header = malloc(sizeof(struct human_header));

        if(NULL != human->human_header)
        {
            f1(human);

            free(human->human_header);
        }
        free(human);
    }
    printf("END\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Also, because struct human contains pointers to other objects, it will be necessary to create those objects as well prior to attempting to use them (like I did to create human_header).  You will also have to deal with `name` as well.

Assuming `struct human_header` will not get more complicated, it probably is better it just define struct human as:

```
struct human
{
    int    number;
    char*  name;
}
```

Couple of other warnings:

1. if you are allocating dynamic memory, always make sure that that allocation works, as I did above.
2. if you are allocating dynamic memory, always make sure that your remember to free that memory as I demonstrated above.  As you noticed, the code has already started to grow more complicated, so I would suggest creating a function to properly create a new human structure (maybe initHuman) and a function for properly cleaning up a human structure (mabey delHuman).
3. final caveat, in the mallocs you want to use the size of the structure and not the size of the pointer to the structure; i.e. `malloc(sizeof(struct human))` and not `malloc(sizeof(struct human*))` -- this is another common error that we all do at least once when we start.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a non initialized pointer to f(1), which is OK (but probably not what you want).
Then you try to access a struc field when your pointer is only of the TYPE of the struct, but the struct itself does not exists...

You can follow what's happening with this code (it is really your code with printf..):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct human {
  struct human_header *human_header;
  char *name;
};

struct human_header {
  unsigned short number;
};

void f2(struct human_header *human_header) {

  human_header->number = 1;
}

void f1(struct human *human) {
    printf("%p \n", human);
  f2(human->human_header);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv) {
  struct human *human;
  printf("%p\n", human);
  f1(human);
  printf("END\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In f2() he's also trying to access uninitialized variable